# how to print document in excel

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hi guys I am new user for PHP.Actually I want to know about any function of java-script to print document in excel format.Please provide me information regarding to this question

Comment: You shall accept an answer for everyone to know what solved your problem. This also keeps the SO ecosystem going.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit confused about your question, since you say you're new to PHP and then talk about javascript, then speak about printing but I believe you mean 'writing a'.

Anyway, a very usefull class is [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) , which is pretty easy to implement and it's docs are very detailed (has also API documentation). The examples provided in the guide should get you started good, if you have any problems just come back and ask a detailed and clear question.

Answer (score 2):

Save it in [csv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) format, which can easily be [imported](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-HP010099725.aspx) in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate .XLS file using a class available on PHPCLASSES.org. [Here is the link](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2037-PHP-Generate-spreadsheet-files-Excel-xls-XML-format.html)